# Is it a good practice to embed a UI component in a .NET Standard class library?

Tags: .net, wpf, desktop-application, windows-forms-designer, .net-standard

The previous .NET developer left the position and I need to be temporarily responsible for it, I am definitely a .NET newbie and please pardon me if there is some wrong understanding/statement.

Description:

I have a class library targeting **.NET Standard 2.0**, the library's main function is to communicate with some bluetooth devices. There is a requirement from the product that the class library needs to provide a UI component in it and the application or whoever consumes the library could use that UI component inside the library and display it.

My questions:

1. My understanding so far is that a UI component can only be displayed in an application that has GUI (WPF and Windows Forms Application), but given that the consuming application can have no GUI at all such as a console app or a windows service, is it even possible to show some UI component in those kinds of applications?
2. Let's assume that the requirement is to only show the UI component in applications that have GUI, what kind of UI component should I use/inherit so that it can be used by both WPF and Forms applications?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a requirement I have not seen before, specifying where certain functionality should exist.  I would typically put the classes that need to interact with hardware or really any non UI related bits in one assembly (.net standard), then UI related controls and such in a separate (.net desktop, .net core).  xyz.bluetooth.infrastructure and zyx.bluetooth.ui for lack of better names.  Having said that, I do not believe you can place WPF related classes in a .NET standard library.

Comment: @RobGoodwin to summarize, you are saying that just leave the non UI related code in the class library targeting .NET Standard, and then create a separate class library for the UI component? Should I create one library for WPF and another one for Forms then, or I can create one single UI library that can be shared between those two applications?

Comment: I would think including them in the same assembly would be fine.  I tend to go too far sometimes breaking things out.  The main thing for me is that if I want to write some back end service or something that would utilize the utility library, I don't want to impose the UI dependencies on the service if it is not needed.

Comment: Please note, that WPF components might not be usable in a .NET Standard 2.0 library according [to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard): "Referencing .NET Framework libraries doesn't work for all projects, such as libraries that use Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) APIs."